# String beside DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a News Site in MVC 5, I have a field named Source, Users don't want to have all media's  name in the dropdownList (because it will be a lot of items, so sometimes they want to save a media  that is not inside the dropdownList and they want to save it  and I need a text box beside the dropdownList, I need a mechanism to  grabe  text box like `@Html.TextBox("SourceInput")` beside the dropdownList  inside Edit method, When I want to get string although  it comes and it's been seen in debugging but  in the line contain (`ModelState.IsValid`) the line return false value  so I can't save changes

```
public ActionResult Edit(string SourceInput, [Bind(Include = "id,Source,DateM,Issue,Subject")] News_ news_)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       if (SourceInput != null) news_.Source = SourceInput;  // SourceInput gets value  but  ModelState.IsValid prevents code  to come here
       db.Entry(news_).State = EntityState.Modified;
       . . . . . . 
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me

Tanks a lot

Tomas

Comment: Debug and inspect `ModelState` for items that have a non-empty `Errors` collection.

Comment: You have not shown your model or what validation attributes have been applied to its properties or the view. Show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friend send this note  and with his guide my problem was resolved:
Hi Tomas,

You can remove the validation for the DropDownList and the Source field. Then, modify your code as below:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string SourceInput, string DropDownListSeletedValue [Bind(Include = "id,Source,DateM,Issue,Subject")] News_ news_)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   if (SourceInput != null) news_.Source = SourceInput;  // SourceInput gets value  but  ModelState.IsValid prevents code  to come here

   else if (DropDownListSeletedValue != null)
   ... //using dropdownslit selected value
   else
   ... //set default value

   db.Entry(news_).State = EntityState.Modified;
   . . . . . . 
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
}
```

Comment: Suggest you ignore your friends advice and go to the MVC site and learn the basics.